# Fetching attribute value from property using ant - may be with propertyregex

Tags: ant

I tried using linecontainsregexp within filterchain ant-task by framing regexp pattern holding unique server name say 'act1' & now property holds value like this:

```
<Server name="act1" value="ServerName" port="1234"></Server>
```

How to get individual attribute names?. For eg if I want to get port #, how to retrieve it. I tried with something like:

```
<propertyregex property="extracted.prop" input="${server.details}"
                               regexp="(.*)\\ *@@" select="\1" />
```

thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are attempting.  Is the `Server` tag in the same ant file, or are you parsing it from another?

Comment: It is part of different xml file & I am running below to get server details in server.details property:

<loadfile property="server.details" srcfile="${baseDir}/build/myTest.xml">
                    <filterchain>
                        <linecontainsregexp>
                            <regexp pattern=".Server name\=.@{server.name}."/>
                        </linecontainsregexp>
                    </filterchain>
                </loadfile>

Comment: Ok, so you are loading the entire XML file with the `Server` tag and you plan to use a regular expression to break the `Server` attributes into separate properties.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Sorry if I am not clear at my first point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work to extract each of the three attributes.  First, notice that I'm loading the entire xml file.  It isn't necessary to extract the specific line as you were doing.  Secondly, I wrote it to be flexible enough to allow line breaks in the `Server` properties and to allow any order of the attributes.

I see that you were really struggling with the regex in particular.  For your understanding, I'll break down the first regex:

```
(?s)    // DOTALL flag. Causes the . wildcard to match newlines.
\x3c    // The < character. For reasons I don't understand, `propertyregex` doesn't allow <
Server  // Match 'Server' literally
.*?     // Reluctantly consume characters until...
name=   // 'name=' is reached
&quot;  // Because ant is an XML file, we must use this escape sequence for "
(.*?)   // Reluctantly grab all characters in a capturing group until...
&quot;  // another double quote is reached.
```

And finally the XML:

```
<loadfile property="server.details" srcfile="${baseDir}/build/myTest.xml"/>
<propertyregex property="server.name"  
               input="${server.details}" 
               regexp="(?s)\x3cServer.*?name=&quot;(.*?)&quot;" 
               select="\1" />
<propertyregex property="server.value" 
               input="${server.details}" 
               regexp="(?s)\x3cServer.*?value=&quot;(.*?)&quot;" 
               select="\1" />
<propertyregex property="server.port"  
               input="${server.details}" 
               regexp="(?s)\x3cServer.*?port=&quot;(.*?)&quot;" 
               select="\1" />
```

Comment: just to add. .. It worked fine for me with small tweaking per requirement of looping.

Actually I have multiple entries for 'Server' details in xml file. So I need to reset with <var name="server.details" unset=true>

And also need to add 'override=true' within <propertyregex , as property's are immutable in ant.

Comment: And is there any documentation link which holds details on escaping character's mapping value, like from above eg: < mapping to \x3c

Comment: The mapping is `\xhh` or `\uhhhh` where the h's are the ASCII/Unicode value for the character.  I just used the Windows Character Map to find the value for `<`.

Comment: thanks, I did found after little research. Found this link useful as well: http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=-&mode=char

 and bad from ant that it cannot handle special/meta character in string!

Comment: Is there any way to escape or resolve if value of attribute has metachar like '-' in it. I tried escaping with \x2d - but not to avail any good result. It throws something like :  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index ..

Comment: It is like below: ( I am using it in filterchain-linecontainsregexp )

<regexp pattern="(?s)\x3cServer.*?value=&quot;@{server.name}&quot;"/>

if 'server.name' has hyphen (-) in it, then it is throwing above exception. Sorry for extending discussion in comments

Comment: oh! I got you.  I should have thought about that.  You need to quote it:  `<regexp pattern="(?s)\x3cServer.*?value=&quot;\Q@{server.name}\E&quot;"/>`  The `\Q` and `\E` tells the regex parser to treat the text as a literal rather than as regex special characters.